# how to show warning icon with a hover text in knockout to warn duplicate record entered in textbox

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am new to both Jquery and Knockout...I am using KO observable array to bind data in grid (using HTML table), i would like to show warning icon with hover text when user enter same values in textbox which already available in KO array(data already shown in grid)...my message should display previous value and stepNo at which its already used. I have two template for grid, one is to display record and other is for Edit

Script part:

```
function UniqueViewModel(){
    var dataValues=ko.observableArray([{stepNo:1,stepText:"test1"},
                                       {stepNo:2,stepText:"test2"},
                                       {stepNo:3,stepText:"test3"},
                                       {stepNo:4,stepText:"test4"}])

}
ko.applyBindings(new UniqueViewModel());

HTML:
```

```
\\View Template
<tbody data-bind="foreach:dataValues">
    <tr>
        <td data-bind="text: stepNo"> </td>
        <td data-bind="text: stepText"> </td>   
    </tr>
</tbody>

\\Edit Template
<tbody data-bind="foreach:dataValues">
    <tr>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind:"value:stepNo"/></td>
        <td><input type="text" data-bind:"value:stepText"/></td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Instead of putting plain js objects to observable array you could create a custom js class that will contain computed observable for getting hint:

```
function Step(no, text, parentObject) {
  var self = this;
  var parent = parentObject;

  self.stepNo = ko.observable(no);
  self.stepText = ko.observable(text);

  self.notUniqueHint = ko.computed(function () {
    var duplicate = ko.utils.arrayFirst(parent.dataValues(), function (item) {
      return item.stepText() == self.stepText() && item.stepNo() != self.stepNo();
    })

    if (duplicate) {
      return "Item is duplicated Step #" + duplicate.stepNo() + " with text - " + duplicate.stepText();
    }

    return "";
  });
}

function UniqueViewModel() {
  var self = this;
  self.dataValues = ko.observableArray();
  self.dataValues.push(new Step(1, "Test1", self));
  self.dataValues.push(new Step(2, "Test2", self));
  self.dataValues.push(new Step(3, "Test3", self));
}

ko.applyBindings(new UniqueViewModel());
```

And update html accordingly:

```
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:dataValues">
    <tr>
      <td data-bind="text: stepNo"></td>
      <td data-bind="text: stepText"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach:dataValues">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: stepNo" />
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="text" data-bind="value: stepText" />
        <img width='16px' data-bind="visible: notUniqueHint, attr: {title: notUniqueHint}" src='http://www.veryicon.com/icon/preview/System/Function/warning%2048%20Icon.jpg'
        />
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vyshniakov/mbBZC/2/

P.S. Your html had some syntax errors, I corrected them.

Comment: A little late, but I think `notUniqueHint` will always be true because it will compare the `Step` to itself (unless `parent.dataValues` does not yet contain this `Step`.